# Как покрыть Activity тестами?

Tags: java, android

Настаиваю библиотеку `Jacoco`. Пишу код в `Android Studio 3.0`. Есть `MainActivity`:

```
package houzz.com.hellojacoco;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.hide).setOnClickListener(this);
        text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
            text.setText("Hello World!");
        } else {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Для экрана есть тест `MainActivityTest`:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        onView(withId(R.id.hide)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.hide)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.text)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));
    }
}
```

В `gradle` подключил создание отчетов о покрытии кода, согласно [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613951):

```
android {
   buildTypes {
      debug {
         testCoverageEnabled = true
      }
   }
}
```

Далее запустил задачу проверки:

```
./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

В отчете по пути `hellojacoco\app\build\reports\coverage\debug\index.html` получаю результат в 0% покртытия тестами. Как покрыть код Activity на 100%? Может по другому настроить? Стандартный отчет из `Android Studio`, так же показывает 0%

**P.S.**
Пробовал делать по разным статьям, например по [этой](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa). Ни один результат не учитывает тесты из папки`AndroidTest`. Максимум `JUnit` тесты учитываются. Так же в этой статье есть ссылка на `GitHub`, а так же ветка с обновлением для `Android Stduio` 3.0, но у меня все равно отчеты не получаются корректно.

**P.S.S.** Оказывается основная проблемма была в телефоне, отчет с телефона `Samsung` получить не получается, получил через эмулятор. Но работатет все равно не до конца корректно. Вот как сейчас выглядит покрытие `Activity`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть в отчет включается только `test2`, а должен и `test1`. Если удалить `test2`, `test1` учитывается. 
Если тесты объединить в один, покрытие будет 100%, но если их будет много, тогда будет не удобно получать отчеты, о том какие тесты выполнились а какие нет.

[Ссылка](https://github.com/iamtihonov/tempJacoco) на весь проект

Ответ ниже помогает в некоторых моментах лучше понять вопрос, но не дает хорошего решения проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил эту ошибку удалением 3-й строки из gradle:

```
1. testOptions {
2.     animationsDisabled true
3.     execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
4.     unitTests {
5.           includeAndroidResources = true
6.     } 
7. }
```

Подробнее можно почитать на [официальном сайте](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html)

Answer (score 3):

Я когда-то пробовал по вот [этому](https://github.com/OleksandrKucherenko/EspressoTestCoverageApp) настраивать.

И из текста вашего вопроса не совсем понятно какую разметку и код вы используете (я про вторую кнопку - последний пример - непонятно что должно произойти по нажатию)
Это помогло бы понять что не так с тестом.

Но хочу отметить 2 вещи (может вам поможет):

1. Тесты если не указан порядок исполняются в любом порядке (иначе нужно аннотировать класс теста так например `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`)
2. Если вы считаете что нажатие не отрабатывает по тому что провалиается тест - попробуйте заменить `.check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));` на `.check(doesNotExist());`

Но для получения развернутого ответа - выложите пожалуйста полные исходники.

**UPDATED (Добавлено после проверки всех исходников)**

Все отлично у вас работает, но есть моменты:

1. Какого поведения среды исполнения вы ждете при изменении видимости?
   `v.setVisibility(View.GONE);` будет выполнено в потоке UI ПОСЛЕ завершения работы onClick(). Ожидать чего то другого - невозможно. Поэетому jacoco в отчете всегда будет указывать пропущенную инструкцию - тк проверить что она была выполнена она не может физически.
2. В условиях всегда будут пропущенные бранчи - тк оно считатет ВСЕ возможные логические состояния и состояния аргумента. Те null, невозможность вызвать метод итд. Попробуйте сделать обработчики анонимными объектами - я так проверял:

   ```
   findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           text.setText("Hello World!");
       }});
   findViewById(R.id.hide).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }});
   ```

В этом случае не будет пропущенных бранчей. Будет одна пропущенная инструкция (уставка видимости). И покрытие - 93%. Я думаю это лучший из возможных результатов.

А вообще - я бы очень не советовал гоняться за 100% покрытием, особенно если надо "переписывать код под тесты". Ну и надо понимать - что не все корректно оно может учесть, просто в меру особенностей среды исполнения. 
И помнить что оно анализирует ФИНАЛЬНЫЙ скомпилированный код в байткоде. Например если вы switch-case сделаете - будет на каждый выбор по 2 бранча + если это числа то + все пропущенные - те полная хэш-таблица всех состояний. (правда там както обещали фильтр сделать такого - не проверял)

**UPDATED (Дополнительные пояснения по комментариям)**

Я вижу вы все упираетесь - попробую пояснить :)
Объедините все в один тест вот так:

```
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        onView(withId(R.id.hide)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.hide)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));

        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.text)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));
    }
```

И вы получите 100% покрытие и все будет нормально.

Почему? Потому что как я уже и писал:

1. Тесты выполняются не по порядку.
2. У вас по обоим нажатиям срабатывает onClick() и только после его завершения меняется текст или прячется кнопка в UI потоке. Те в памяти получается при 2х раздельных тестах - 2 раздельных асинхронных вызова - и в одном из них одно отработает, в другом другое.

Те в каком порядке тесты выполняются - мы не знаем, в каком порядке асинхронные вызовы и операции изменения текста и видимости произойдут - мы не знаем. Знаем только одно - это изолированные друг от друга вызовы с созданием асинхронной задачи и последующей синхронизацией с UI потоком - а в каком порядке оно будет - "как карта ляжет". Поэтому и такой результат - мы не знаем какую из 2х асинхронных операций оно анализирует.

Какие есть счетчики в jacoco почитайте [тут](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html).
ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО прочтите про анализ покрытия кода [тут](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/flow.html).

И думаю потом вы поймете - что при расстановке проб jacoco - ставит их по вашему коду 'как есть'. А в реальности - там 2 асинхронных вызова + они инициируются 2мя асинхронными тестами. И + это все еще оптимизирует компилятор. Те какая 'каша' из проб и асинхронностей в результате - никто не знает.
Поэтому асинхронные вызовы тестируются только в рамках ОДНОГО теста на покрытие - тк это гарантирет очередность операций.

Можно еще упралять выполнением тестов espresso с помощью [idling resources](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource.html)
Но здесь мы имеем дело с работой анализатора jacoco - в тестах же нет проблем.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69482/discussion-on-answer-by-muritiku---activity-).